# ¿Por qué al intentar guardar una URL con un procedimiento almacenado solo considera un punto?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Lo que quiero es guardar la URLde una imagen, como he visto las URLs se guardan con dos o cuatro diagonales dependiendo, para no se tomen como caracteres especiales y ya lo intenté de esas dos formas, enviando mi cadena de URL con más de una diagonal anexada.

**He debugueado y seguido el proceso de inserción y todo el camino siempre lleva la URL las diagonales adicionales, excepto a la hora de insertar por que lo único que se guarda en el campo de la URL es un ".".**

La dirección va de esta forma en todo el proceso `"..//..//..//css/imagenes//Logo.png"`, en su defecto va con cuatro diagonales pero de ninguna manera se guarda de forma correcta.

La URL debería de ir después de el ultimo pipe `|`, pero solo se ve un punto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de inserción:

```
#region EMPRESA
#region insertar Empresa
public string insertarEmpresa(int idEmpresa, string nombre, string rfc, string direccion, int codPostal, string idEstado, string telefono, string colonia, string pais, string ciudad,int tipoS,string immex,string logo, int idUser, string ip)
{
    establecerConexion();
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader read = null;
        comando = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertarEmpresa", conexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@idEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idEmpresa;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@nomEmpresa", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nombre;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@rfc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rfc;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@direccion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = direccion;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@codPostal", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codPostal;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idEstado;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = telefono;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@colonia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = colonia;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@pais", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pais;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@ciudad", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ciudad;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@tipoS", SqlDbType.Int).Value =tipoS;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@immex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = immex;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@logo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = logo;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@idUser", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idUser;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ciudad;
        conexion.Open();
        read = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.HasRows)
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                result = read.GetValue(0).ToString();
            } return "1";
        }
        else return "1";

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return "2";
    }
    finally
    {
        if (comando != null)
            comando.Dispose();
        conexion.Close();
    }

}
#endregion
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código con el que estás intentando insertar en la base?

Comment: Porque no agregas tu código? creo que sería útil.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo de insercion, gracias por comentar @jorgesys

Comment: ¿Qué valor envías y qué valor recibes en el parámetro `logo`?

Comment: @flxtr envio la url con doble diagonal y lo seteo a mi variable del sp para que esta lo tenga y lo alamcene al ejecutarse

Comment: @David solo se ponen dos diagonales cuando es una diagonal invertida, esto para escapar los caracteres, por ejemplo, si tuvieras esto `"..\\..\\..\\css\\imagenes\\Logo.png"` entonces es correcto. Cambia el contenido de la variable `string logo` por esto: `"../../../css/imagenes/Logo.png"` y realiza la prueba

Comment: @David que tipo de dato y longitud tiene el parámetro `@logo` en tu procedimiento.

Comment: @Flxtr, cuando dice: "He debugueado y seguido el proceso de inserción y todo el camino siempre lleva la URL...", el problema está en la inserción a la BD ya que puede ser que el parámetro o la columna de la tabla no tengan una longitud adecuada.

Comment: @davlio, como puedo saber si mi longitud es adecuada?

Comment: @David favor de modificar tu pregunta y agregar la información de tu parámetro `@logo` (la parte inicial de la definición de tu procedimiento almacenado) como de la columna a donde estás agregando.

Comment: Estás seguro de que esta linea es correcta? `comando.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ciudad;`? Entiendo que en lugar de ciudad debería ser ip,no es asi?

Comment: @pikoh no no me habia dado cuenta, rayos gracias por la observacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no está ligado al código, sino al Proceso Almacenado, posiblemente en el SP tengas algo como lo siguiente:

```
@miParametro VARCHAR
```

Ahí estás declarando un parámetro de tipo Varchar de un largo de 1 y aunque envíes un string de un largo n > 1, el parámetro solo tomará el primer caracter. Lo que debes hacer es cambiarlo a un largo que sepas que te alcanzará para recibir la información.

```
@miParametro VARCHAR(200)
```

Igual sí tuvieras parámetros de tipo `Nvarchar`, debes especificar el largo.

Comment: @David podrías indicarnos como está declarado el parámetro `@logo` en tu procedimiento almacenado, como también que longitud tiene la columna de la tabla donde guardas el valor de dicho parámetro.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el codigo puesto me queda la duda de porque un SqlReader en un procedimiento de insertar registros?

```
    read = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (read.HasRows)
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            result = read.GetValue(0).ToString();
        } return "1";
    }
    else return "1";
```

Al insertar normalmente usamos

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Si tu procedimiento almacenado ya tiene los parametros establecios y definidos es mas facil usar:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", logo);
```

Y dejar que el comando realice la inferencia de tipo y longitud en base a tu procedimiento almacenado.

Usando la cadena de referencia puesta y probandola en fiddle no deberia de causar ningun problema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8db45/2

Comment: Me parece que el problema no es tanto por la forma en qué está guardando, sino más bien, por el contenido de la información

Comment: Es recomendable usar Parameter.Add que Parameters.AddWithValue http://devtroce.com/2013/03/19/parameters-add-vs-parameters-addwithvalue/